# can't update component correctly with any of life cycles (react)

Tags: reactjs

I have three components `Routes`, `Menu` and a `Page`, and i'm trying to update `Page` (scroll it down to the selected part), when clicked on the corresponding menu item.

This is `Routes` code, it has a state `scrollDestination` which is passed to `Page` as a prop and a `setScrollDestination` method which passed to `Menu` also as a prop.

```
export default class Routes extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        scrollDestination: '#part_1'
    };

    this.setScrollDestination = this.setScrollDestination.bind(this);
}

setScrollDestination(destination) { 
    this.setState({
        scrollDestination : destination
    })
}


render() {
    return (
        <Router onUpdate = {() => {document.body.scrollTop = 0}}>

            <div className="router">

                <Menu text = {this.props.text.header}
                        changeLang = {this.props.changeLang}
                        setScrollDestination = {this.setScrollDestination} />

                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path = "/"
                           render = {(props) => (
                                    <HomePage   text = {this.props.text} 
                                                changeLang = {this.props.changeLang} 
                                                {...props} />
                                    )} />

                    <Route path = "/page"
                           render = {(props) => (
                                    <Page   text = {this.props.text} 
                                            scrollDestination = {this.state.scrollDestination}
                                            {...props} />
                                    )} />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </Router>
    );
}
}
```

`Menu` component pass on destination as a parameter to `setScrollDestination` function and it is updating Routes' state and also `Page`'s prop.

```
export default class Menu extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleCloseClick = this.handleCloseClick.bind(this);
}

handlePageScroll(destination) { this.props.setScrollDestination(destination); }

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li onClick = {this.handlePageScroll.bind(this, '#part_1')}><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/page">Page
                    <ul>
                        <li onClick = {this.handlePageScroll.bind(this, '#part_1')}>part_1</li>
                        <li onClick = {this.handlePageScroll.bind(this, '#part_2')}>part_2</li>
                        <li onClick = {this.handlePageScroll.bind(this, '#part_3')}>part_3</li>
                    </ul></Link>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

`Page` component must only scroll the page. The state is updating, but it ignors some clicks. It does not always work.

```
export default class Page extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    let scrollDestination = nextProps.scrollDestination;
    setTimeout(function() {
            TweenMax.to(window, 1, {scrollTo: {y:scrollDestination, offsetY:100}}); 
        }, 400);
    }
}

render() {
    return (
      <div id="part_1"></div>
      <div id="part_2"></div>
      <div id="part_3"></div>
    );
}

}
```

I've tried all of the updating methods and all of them are work the same. Where can be the issue?

The second thing is that all methods updates the component when ANY props have changed. Is there any way to run methods if one specific prop changed?

Thanks a lot for any answers.